# How display data in the textbox in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting problem to display selected data in textbox
I have following code which display data bellow the text box according to user suggestion

```
$('input[name=profileOrg]').keyup(function(){
    var q = $(this).val();
    $.get("CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php?q="+q, function(data){
       $('#name').html(data).show(); 
});
```

Following is code which give me the list from the database

```
$term = $_GET['q'];
    $query = "SELECT organization_name FROM members WHERE organization_name LIKE '".$term."%'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {       
            //$member[] = $row['organization_name'];
            echo '<a href="#">'.$row['organization_name'].'</a><br>';
        }
```

In this code i can able to display data bellow the text box according to user suggestion but i am getting problem when the user select data from the list how can i display selected value in the textbox?

**I don't want to use jquery UI auto complete**.

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error - the callback has no closing brace: `}`

Comment: @jai i forgot to put the closing brace here but it's there in the code

Answer (score 4):

Use the .val() property. To assign text, use the following:

```
$("#name").val(data);
```

Comment: When the user select data from the list that data i want to display in the textbox. Here is the code which generate data $term = $_GET['q'];
 $query = "SELECT organization_name FROM members WHERE organization_name LIKE '".$term."%'";
 $result = $db->query($query);
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
  {  
   //$member[] = $row['organization_name'];
   echo '<a href="#">'.$row['organization_name'].'</a><br>';
  }

Comment: Call the server-side through AJAX, return a value, assign it.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `$('#name').val(data)` instead of `$('#name').html(data).show();`, the html() functionality is to convert html code into html components example

```
$("p").html("Hello <b>world</b>!");
```

I hope this would help.